# How to optimize speed/memory for java code that is supposed to read the last 5000 lines of a given input

Tags: java, list, performance, memory

I'm writing a code that outputs only the last 5000 lines of an input with an appropriate runtime (if input is less than 5000 lines, then it outputs it all) -- unfortunately, my current solutions are too slow at the moment.

I'm pretty sure I've used up all the "list"-types from queues to stacks to arrayLists, and now to dequeues; but I always get the same execution time on my sample which is pretty slow.

This is what I came up with, let me know of any possible improvements I can do or different angles I can take with it.

```
Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<String>(); //makes deque
        int temp = 0; //counter for input,
        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
            deque.addLast(line); //reads input and puts it into the deque
            temp++; //counter increases by one 
            if(temp >= 5000){        //if the counter gets over 5000, we start chopping off the head
                deque.removeFirst(); //so we can effectively stay on the 5000 lines output mark 
            }
        }
        
        int s = deque.size(); //placeholder so as to not access deque.size often 
        for(int i = 0; i<s; i++){  //for loop -- prints out the deque
            w.println(deque.pop());
        }
```

Comment: Read the file reverse

Comment: I would suggest using a ring buffer in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try use apache commons-io lib to read file in reverse order.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

A simple code like below:

```
File inputFile = new File("file name");
ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(inputFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Stack<String> lines = new Stack<>();
String lineContent;
int count = 0;
while ((lineContent= reader.readLine()) != null && count++ < 5000) {
    lines.add(lineContent);
}

while (!lines.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(lines.pop());
}
```